# FileNotFoundError when trying to create new text file in PyCharm

Tags: python

I am trying to create a text file but when I do I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\XXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-32-3b9fb00bd9fd>", line 6, in <module>
        file = open('test_XXX.txt', 'w')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_XXX.txt'
```

Here is my code:

```
file = open('test_xxxx.txt', 'w')
text = 'Hello, this is a quick test file.\n This is the second line of the file.'
file.write(text)
file.close()
```

Here are the variations of the first line of code that I have tried:

```
f = open("UPDATED_NLP_COURSE/00-Python-Text-Basics/test_xxxx.txt",'w')
```

AND

```
f = open("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/PycharmProjects/PycharmProjects/NLP/UPDATED_NLP_COURSE/00- 
        Python-Text-Basics/test_xxxx.txt",'w')
```

Both the above variations resulted in the same file not found error. Please advise.
Thank you!!

Comment: Nothing to do with PyCharm, the error is a Python error message - the only possible link with PyCharm here is that your script may not be running in the folder where you expected it to run, which can be controlled through PyCharm's run configurations. Check the settings for the working directory in the run configuration you're using. Keep in mind that the default is to run a script in the folder it is in, which would be the default if you just ran the script with Python directly as well. If you need it to run in a certain folder, you could get your script to make sure it is running there.

Comment: I don't understand this error message.  You're opening the file for writing, so it shouldn't matter that the file does not already exist.  Are you _sure_ this is your correct code?

Comment: The error message has `test_XXX.txt` as the filename, but your code has `test_xxxx.txt`.  Please post your real code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is trying to open a file with the name of `test_XXX.txt`.
Your code is creating a file with the name of `test_xxxx.txt`.